# How to keep div text from dropping to bottom of container?

Tags: html, css, plotly

I would like to change the styling of the div text while keeping it at the top of the container. My current script (below) renders the div text at the top of the container without styling (bolding, underlining, italicizing, etc)

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.6.3.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  #chart1 {
     width: 360px;
     height: 400px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100px;
     left: 0px;
     text-align: center;
   }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="chart1">Chart 1 Title</div>
 <script>
  CHART1 = document.getElementById('chart1')
  Plotly.newPlot( CHART1,
     [{
       type: 'pie',
       values: [60,40]
     }],
     {margin: {t:0}}
  )
 </script>
</body>
```

When I simply wrap the div text in:
`<b>text</b>`
it drops the text to the bottom of the container automatically. I can't tell if this is has to do with Plotly being used.

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.6.3.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  #chart1 {
     width: 360px;
     height: 400px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100px;
     left: 0px;
     text-align: center;
   }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="chart1"><b>Chart 1 Title</b></div>
 <script>
  CHART1 = document.getElementById('chart1')
  Plotly.newPlot( CHART1,
     [{
       type: 'pie',
       values: [60,40]
     }],
     {margin: {t:0}}
  )
 </script>
</body>
```

I have tried:

- adding `vertical-align: top;` to the CSS styling
- adjusting the margin elements of the container
- increasing the size of the container to see if the text was simply getting "squeezed" to bottom

Can anyone spot the mistake I've made or the workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the first example:
it is

`<div id="chart1"> Chart 1 Title <div> pieChart here </div> </div>`

while in second snippet:
it is

`<div id="chart1"> <div> pieChart here </div> <b> Chart 1 Title </b> </div>`

Therefor title in the second snippet is below pieChart div

you need to insert **your title before pieChart div**, see below

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.6.3.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  #parentDiv {
     width: 360px;
     height: 400px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100px;
     left: 0px;
     text-align: center;
   }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="parentDiv">
   <b>Chart 1 Title</b>
   <div id="chart1"></div>
 </div>
 <script>
  CHART1 = document.getElementById('chart1')
  Plotly.newPlot( CHART1,
     [{
       type: 'pie',
       values: [60,40]
     }],
     {margin: {t:0}}
  )
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Can you add in how to keep the chart title text centered on the container? ```<div style="text-align: center;"</div>``` aligns the chart title to the whole page

Comment: Can you specify which container since if you apply `text-align`, it applies on the children of the element.  so in your case parentDiv's children will be aligned center inside parentDiv

Comment: I applied it to your parentDiv, but the "Chart 1 title" text is aligned with respect to the entire page, not the chart child

Comment: I am sorry I am not getting your query however running snippet it works perfectly. please see `<style>` section. The css is now for `parentDiv` and not for `chart1` and it has text-align already in it. If you copy the style section plus the html, it must work.

Comment: I have multiple columns of charts so I need each charts title to be centered on each chart which this doesnt seem to be achieving. I will mark as accepted answer though because it accomplishes my original question. Thanks!

Comment: I think every chart must have parentDiv like div. Simply replicate parentDiv for each chart but you have to control the css positioning. Now each of those div if using a css lib can be easily controlled such as with bootstrap cols or using css flex.